# Saving the Record on Salesforce 1 (Gives Error)

Tags: salesforce1-app

My user running his mobile Salesforce1 then showing this Error.while saving the record.

**"There's a problem saving this record. You might not have permission to edit, or might have been deleted or archived."**

​I also checked his profile and the permissions is seems to be right , he is Salesforce 1 User. How can help this user to Save  via Salesforce1 on the case ?

Comment: Praveen the profile may not have right access to object .Are you able to modify record from the desktop

Comment: @MohithShrivastava i am able to do the save from desktop but , this is the issue with only one salesforce 1 user in that profile .